# How to include options passed to npm installer when including dependencies in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

I am very new to node.js so please pardon my ignorance on a simple question. I am adding dependencies to package.json for a node.js application and am wondering if it's possible to specify command line arguments that would normally be passed to npm install. For example, when installing the mongodb package from the command line, you might need to pass an option:

```
npm install mongodb --mongodb:native
```

Is their a way with the package.json syntax to specify that a package should be installed with command line options?

Comment: You can still pass the args - they are processed by each dependency individually. See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185411/best-workflow-using-node-js-npm-and-git/9198374#9198374

Answer (score 4):

It's not perfect, but I have been able to get around this problem by adding an explicit npm install into the preinstall script of my package.json file.  In this way, the mongodb package is added as a binary before npm gets a chance to do it incorrectly.  Hope this helps

```
"scripts": {
  "preinstall" : "npm install mongodb '--mongodb:native'"
}
```